# How can I shorten getting dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

Currently I am getting 14 dates using `moment` and the following:

```
today = moment()
yesterday = moment().subtract(1, "d")
two_days_ago = moment().subtract(2, "d")
three_days_ago = moment().subtract(3 "d")
...
two_weeks_ago = moment().subtract(14, "d")
```

This makes my code long and not very nice to use.

How can I get 14 different dates without explicitly stating them as above?

Comment: Do a for loop and store dates in array/object

Comment: You could add your own method to the `moment` constructor that subtracts `x` days

Comment: I'm new to Javascript so not sure where to begin with those suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop and store dates in the array:

```
var dates=[];
for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
  var date = moment().subtract(i, 'days');
  dates.push(date);
}
```

The dates array will contain your dates.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for. If I wanted to get a range between 7 days ago and 14 days ago how could I achieve that?